# Having to restart server laravel 4 for changes to take effect

Tags: laravel-4, mamp, mamp-pro

I am working on the css on a laravel server and I noticed that I have to restart MAMP (working on a Mavericks computer) every time I change even the smallest code for the new code to take effect. I know laravel caches their views, but on another computer running MAMP PRO, I do not have to restart MAMP PRO for the changes to take effect. On yet another computer running MAMP PRO I have the same problem I previously stated, which leads me to believe that I can fix the problem. How would I go about doing so?

Comment: are you using an asset manager of some sort that minifies and/or concatenates your CSS?  If yes, the caching is going on there, not in Laravel itself.  Laravel itself does not cache these resources as they are not related to server side processing, only client side, where Laravel doesn't actually exist.

Comment: I am not using anything like that.

Comment: I honestly don't know what can be happening.  I edit my CSS all the time and haven't restarted my server in months.  I don't even know how a server side PHP framework would cache client side CSS.  Are you including your CSS into your `Blade` templates using `{{ HTML::style('url') }}` ?

Comment: No I am doing <link href="{{asset('url')}}" rel.....

Comment: Is there any chance that the client is caching it?  Have you tried not restarting the server and just clearing your cache, or perhaps using a different computer?

Comment: Well, as I said on another computer it works fine. The one that doesnt work is a MacBook Air with MAMP and the one that does work is a MacBook Pro with Retina display with MAMP Pro. Both computers are using the latest chrome and Laravel 4.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the version of php you use from the MAMP preferences pane.

Now, you want to edit your php.ini file for that version, and then restart MAMP.

The reason it is caching is because some versions of MAMP by default turn on OPCache.

```
sudo nano /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/[php-version]/conf/php.ini
```

Then, look for **OPCache** towards the end of the php.ini file, and comment out everything relating to it.